# Prove that $aH\cap bH= \emptyset$ iff $b\notin aH$ and $a\in bH~ \text{iff}~ b\in aH$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that
>
> (i) $aH\cap bH= \emptyset$ iff $b\notin aH$ and
>
> (ii) $a\in bH~ \text{iff}~ b\in aH$
>
> where $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $a,b\in G$.

Attempt:

(i)
We know either $aH= bH$ or $aH\cap bH= \emptyset$. Then if $aH\cap bH= \emptyset$, then $aH\neq bH$. Then $b=be\in bH$ that implies $b\notin aH$ as $b\in bH$ & $aH\cap bH= \emptyset$.

I don't know whether the proof is correct or not. Also how to show the converse part of (i). Please help me to solve both the problems.

Comment: The statement $b \notin bH$ is never true since $b = be$ and $e \in H$.

Comment: @SamBirns Yes I have corrected.

Comment: Notice that if $ aH \cap bH \neq \emptyset $, then $ ah_1=bh_2 $ for some $ h_1,h_2 \in H $. Thus, $ b=ah_1h_2^{-1} \in aH $, as desired.

Comment: Given $aH \cap bH = \emptyset$ not $aH \cap bH \neq \emptyset$ ??

Comment: Note the correct symbol $\verb|\emptyset|$ for the empty set $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part (i):

> Let $aH\cap bH= \emptyset$. If $b\in aH$, then $b=ah$, for some $h\in H$. So, $a=bh^{-1}\in bH$ implies that $a\in aH\cap bH$, a contradiction.
>
> Let $b\notin aH$. If $c\in aH \cap bH \neq \emptyset$, then $c=ah=bh'$ for some $h,h' \in H$, and so $b=ahh'^{-1} \in aH$, a contradiction.

Part (ii):

> Let $a\in bH$. So, $a=bh$, for some $h\in H$, and we have $b=ah^{-1}\in aH$.
> Let $b\in aH$. So, $b=ah$, for some $h\in H$, and we have $a=bh^{-1}\in bH$.